# Omnet++ Simulation failing to run makefile

Tags: networking, simulation, omnet++

I'm currently an undergraduate researcher and I've been tasked with researching knowledge defined networking. The research in particular deals with very advanced code that's way beyond my minimal knowledge of omnet. The first instruction to build the network is to run the makefile (found here: https://bpaste.net/show/d26a592a563a) to generate the "networkRL" needed by the python script.

I've imported all of the files needed for the simulation but whenever I try to run the makefile I get an error:

"Error starting process.

> Cannot run program "C:\Users\Sierra\DRL\omnet\router\makefile": Launching failed"

Or when I try to run the entire simulation it asks:

> "Enter parameter 'NetworkAll.node0.tcontroller.folderName':"

I'm not sure if these are simple problems to solve and I'm just inexperienced, but any help would be greatly appreciated. I can post all of the source, ned, and header files if necessary. I didn't want to pack this entire post with 15+ code links if the makefile was the only one needed to solve this issue.

I'm using OMNeT version 4.6 on Windows 10 if that information is relevant

Answer (score 1):

The term "run the makefile" means: run `make` in the directory where `makefile` is located. In `OMNeT++` one can do this in two ways. 
**First way**:

1. Open `mingwenv.cmd` from `OMNeT++` main directory.
2. In the mingw console go to main directory of the project, for example:

   ```
   cd /C/Users/Sierra/DRL/
   ```
3. In the mingw console type:

   ```
   make
   ```

**Second way**:

1. In `OMNeT++` choose `File` | `Import..` |`Existing Project into Workspace` and select the project.
2. Build the project choosing `Project` | `Build Project`.

---

According the second error: open `omnetpp.ini` and set value for `folderName` parameter, for example:

```
    **.folderName = "/c/some/directory"
```

or

```
    **.node0.tcontroller.folderName = "/c/some/directory"
```